# Python Dictionary: "in" vs "get"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash

I am a little confused between the use of "in" vs "get" when searching for an element within the dictionary.

According to this time complexity table, [**here**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity): when using "in" we get O(n) vs "get" we get O(1).

**In these two code snippets below,** they achieve the same thing, but apparently using get will be much faster?

```
#Recall that for "get" the second parameter is returned if key is not found

#O(1) time complexity
if dict.get(key, False):
   return "found item"

#O(n) time complexity
if key in dict:
   return "found item"
```

I do not understand how using a get would change the time complexity when they can both achieve the same thing. Except the get call will actually return the value if its found.

**Questions:** How is it that "in" time complexity is O(n) while "get" is only O(1) when they both achieve the same results? Is there ever a reason to use "in" with dictionaries if this is true?

Comment: That's the time complexity for `in` in a *list*.

Comment: That link doesn't say what you think it says. The time complexity for both is the same

Comment: For a dict, `in` and `get()` are both `O(1)` expected time but `O(len(dict))` worst case.  `in` is the obvious way to test for membership, so use it.  `dict.get(key, False)` isn't even correct (e.g., suppose key is 0, or some other "false-like" value).

Comment: @Tim Right, I hadn't thought about that, thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`get()` returns the value for the given key, if the key exists in the dict.

`in` returns a boolean value depending on if the key is present in the dict.

Use `get()` if you need the value. Use `in` if you only need to test if the key exists.

Comment: But as I stated using "in" time complexity is worse than just using "get". So why ever use "in"? I can achieve the same results with "get" which is much faster

Comment: @Phillip Read the tables carefully on the link you gave. The time complexity of `in` is given for a list, not a dict.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you mean that when whe use dict doesn't matter time complexity but if it is a list you have to be carfully about using in right?

Comment: @allexiusw No, Time complexity is important for both data structures so you can decide the correct one to use. However, the OP was reading the documentation incorrectly. They were looking at the time complexity of `in` used with a list which is different than when you use `in` with a dict. The wiki has been edited since the previous comments were made here so they are no longer even relevant.

Comment: Time complexity for `in` and `get` is same for dict. [Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#:~:text=is%20a%20list.-,dict,-The%20Average%20Case)