# python dictionary .get() vs element in dictionary giving different results in DP based recursion program

Tags: python, dictionary

dictionary get vs in behaving differently in cansum code

```
def canSum(targetSum, numbers, memo=None):
    if memo == None:
        memo = {}

    if targetSum in memo:
        return memo[targetSum]
    if targetSum == 0:
        return True
    if targetSum < 0:
        return False

    for n in numbers:
        remainder = targetSum - n
        if canSum(remainder, numbers, memo):
            memo[targetSum] = True
            return True

    memo[targetSum] = False
    return False


print(canSum(7, [2, 3])) # True
print(canSum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7])) # True
print(canSum(7, [2, 4])) # False
print(canSum(8, [2, 3, 5])) # True
print(canSum(3000, [7, 14])) # False -> Works fast with large inputs!
```

When replacing the 4th line with if memo.get(targetSum) the function does not work for the last input, keeps running due to huge time complexity

```
def canSum(targetSum, numbers, memo=None):
    if memo == None:
        memo = {}

    if memo.get(targetSum,False):
        return memo[targetSum]
    if targetSum == 0:
        return True
    if targetSum < 0:
        return False

    for n in numbers:
        remainder = targetSum - n
        if canSum(remainder, numbers, memo):
            memo[targetSum] = True
            return True

    memo[targetSum] = False
    return False


print(canSum(7, [2, 3])) # True
print(canSum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7])) # True
print(canSum(7, [2, 4])) # False
print(canSum(8, [2, 3, 5])) # True
print(canSum(3000, [7, 14])) # False -> Keeps running no output obtained
```

Can anyone explain the reason why? I am aware of how .get and in work differently, have enclosed related SO threads below:

[Why does this solution work in Javascript but not in Python? (Dynamic programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428535/why-does-this-solution-work-in-javascript-but-not-in-python-dynamic-programmin)

[Python Dictionary: "in" vs "get"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509361/python-dictionary-in-vs-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two versions of your code are not equivalent.

In the case where `memo[targetSum]` exists and is `False`, the block:

```
if targetSum in memo:
    return memo[targetSum]
```

will return `False`, but

```
if memo.get(targetSum,False):
    return memo[targetSum]
```

won't execute the `return`, as `memo.get(targetSum,False)` is `False`. In this case, you will run the loop at the end of the function.